# Reading line-by-line in two files simultaneously in Bash Script

Tags: linux, shell, csv, ubuntu, parsing

I have 2 files named as `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`. Contents are as follows :

```
file1.csv:
a
b
c
d
```

and

```
file2.csv:
1
2
3
4
```

How can I write a shell (bash) script to print as below :

```
Expected Outcome :
a and 1
b and 2
c and 3
d and 4
```

Comment: `paste -d ' ' file1.txt <(yes and|head -n $(wc -l <file1.txt)) file2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse `paste` and separate the columns with an equals sign or some other unlikely character, then replace it with `and`:

```
paste -d= file{1,2}.csv | sed 's/=/ and /'
```

---

Or, somewhat uglier, but maybe more reliable, use FS *"File Separator"*, hex code `1a`, like `gawk` uses `SUBSEP`:

```
paste -d$'\x1c' file{1,2}.csv | sed 's/\x1c/ and /'
```